# How to replace characters by strtok function - C?

Tags: c, string, strtok

I really want to change all spaces ' ' in my char array for NULL -

```
#include <string.h>

void ReplaceCharactersInString(char *pcString, char *cOldChar, char *cNewChar) {
    char *p = strtok(pcString, cOldChar);
    strcpy(pcString, p);
    while (p != NULL) {
        strcat(pcString, p);
        p = strtok(cNewChar, cOldChar);
    }          
}

int main() {
    char pcString[] = "I am testing";
    ReplaceCharactersInString(pcString, " ", NULL);
    printf(pcString);
}
```

OUTPUT: `Iamtesting`

If I simply put the `printf(p)` function before:

```
p = strtok(cNewChar, cOldChar);
```

In the result I  have what I need - but the problem is how to store it in `pcString` (directly)?

Or there is maybe a better solution to simply do it?

Comment: Just for learning purposes, why do you want to convert whitespaces into null characters?

Comment: I want to decoding tokens for particular type - string, numbers -  next functions require this.

Comment: What if `p` is initially `NULL`? You don't check for this, and the `strcpy` would segfault.

Comment: @CraigEstey You're quite right, I'm getting a segfault message on debugger on the exact `strcpy()` line. I'm not sure what actually getting fault.

Comment: The code is a mess all around, take a close look to [what strtok does and how it's used](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok)

Comment: By *replacing with NULL*, do you mean removing the characters?

Comment: @chqrlie By replacing with NULL I mean - cut all spaces from this string and change it to NULL => instead of I am testingNULL i want to have  INULLamNULLtestingNULL.

Comment: @AlwaysDissapointed: You do not want to get the string *INULLamNULLtestingNULL*, you want `"I\0am\0testing\0"` and some indication on the actual end of the string. You might want to allocate an array of pointers and make them point to the words.

Answer (score 1):

While some functions expect a [single] string to be pre-parsed to: `I\0am\0testing`, that is *rare*.

And, if you have *multiple* spaces/delimiters, you'll get (e.g.) `foo\0\0bar`, which you probably don't want.

And, your `printf` in `main` will only print the *first* token in the string because it will stop on the *first* EOS (i.e. '\0').

(i.e.) You probably don't want `strcpy/strcat`.

More likely, you want to fill an array of `char *` pointers to the tokens you parse.

So, you'd want to pass down `char **argv`, then do: `argv[argc++] = strtok(...);` and then do: `return argc`

---

Here's how I would refactor your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ARGMAX  100

int
ReplaceCharactersInString(int argmax,char **argv,char *pcString,
    const char *delim)
{
    char *p;
    int argc;

    // allow space for NULL termination
    --argmax;

    for (argc = 0;  argc < argmax;  ++argc, ++argv) {
        // get next token
        p = strtok(pcString,delim);
        if (p == NULL)
            break;

        // zap the buffer pointer
        pcString = NULL;

        // store the token in the [returned] array
        *argv = p;
    }

    *argv = NULL;

    return argc;
}

int
main(void)
{
    char pcString[] = "I am testing";
    int argc;
    char **av;
    char *argv[ARGMAX];

    argc = ReplaceCharactersInString(ARGMAX,argv,pcString," ");

    printf("argc: %d\n",argc);
    for (av = argv;  *av != NULL;  ++av)
        printf("'%s'\n",*av);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here's the output:

```
argc: 3
'I'
'am'
'testing'
```

Comment: I disagree with your assumptions of what OP does or does not want.

Comment: @Cheatah That's nice, but in what way? Just putting 00 in the string without a way to get at the individual tokens isn't terribly useful. However, it's what `/proc/self/cmdline` does, so it is possible. Doing what I did _does_ embed the EOS on the original string. Others did the `char **` approach--it's what chrqlie did in his answer. Since OP's post is a bit vague, OP has to respond/clarify if s/he doesn't get what s/he wants. And OP did say: _Or there is maybe a better solution to simply do it?_ If OP wants to _remove_ spaces s/he needs to say that, but the code is totally different for that

Comment: If OP states that they "*really* wants to change all spaces ' ' in my char array for NULL", I'll take their word for it. And so I'll also disagree that OP was vague about it.

Comment: @Cheatah That was _not_ part of OP's post, just a recent comment (16 hours after my post) And, it's still vague because `NULL` means `#define NULL (void *) 0` as opposed to an embedded `'\0'` So, how can OP actually _use_ the result? This is beginning to look like an XY problem: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Answer (score 1):

`strcat` `strcpy` should not be used when the source and destination overlap in memory.

Iterate through the array and replace the matching character with the desired character.
Since zeros are part of the string, `printf` will stop at the first zero and `strlen` can't be used for the length to print. `sizeof` can be used as `pcString` is defined in the same scope.
Note that `ReplaceCharactersInString` would not work a second time as it would stop at the first zero. The function could be written to accept a length parameter and loop using the length.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void ReplaceCharactersInString(char *pcString, char cOldChar,char cNewChar){
    while ( pcString && *pcString) {//not NULL and not zero
        if ( *pcString == cOldChar) {//match
            *pcString = cNewChar;//replace
        }
        ++pcString;//advance to next character
    }
}

int main ( void) {
    char pcString[] = "I am testing";
    ReplaceCharactersInString ( pcString, ' ', '\0');
    for ( int each = 0; each < sizeof pcString; ++each) {
        printf ( "pcString[%02d] = int:%-4d char:%c\n", each, pcString[each], pcString[each]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to split the string into individual tokens separated by spaces such as `"I\0am\0testing\0"`. You can use `strtok()` for this but this function is error prone. I suggest you allocate an array of pointers and make them point to the words. Note that splitting the source string is sloppy and does not allow for tokens to be adjacent such as in `1+1`. You could allocate the strings instead.

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **split_string(const char *str, char *delim) {
    size_t i, len, count;
    const char *p;

    /* count tokens */
    p = str;
    p += strspn(p, delim);      // skip initial delimiters
    count = 0;
    while (*p) {
        count++;
        p += strcspn(p, delim); // skip token
        p += strspn(p, delim);  // skip delimiters
    }

    /* allocate token array */
    char **array = calloc(sizeof(*array, count + 1);
    p = str;
    p += strspn(p, delim);      // skip initial delimiters
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        len = strcspn(p, delim); // token length
        array[i] = strndup(p, len); // allocate a copy of the token
        p += len;               // skip token
        p += strspn(p, delim);  // skip delimiters
    }
    /* array ends with a null pointer */
    array[count] = NULL;
    return array;
}

int main() {
    const char *pcString = "I am testing";
    char **array = split_string(pcString, " \t\r\n");
    for (size_t i = 0; array[i] != NULL; i++) {
        printf("%zu: %s\n", i, array[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `strtok` function pretty much does exactly what you want. It basically replaces the next delimiter with a `'\0'` character and returns the pointer to the current token. The next time you call `strtok`, you should pass a `NULL` argument (see the documentation for `strtok`) and it will point to the next token, which will again be delimited by `'\0'`. Read some more examples of correct `strtok` usage.